# Count dismatch between 2 rows from 2 different tables - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with 2 tables. **table1** and **table2**.

**Table1** contains a list of tests ( column '**name**' ). And I want to count how many rows are missing in **table2** ( this table has also a column '**name**' ) according to the list of tests of **table1**.
So I just want to count the mismatch between table1.name and table2.name.

I tried several querys, but all didnt really work.
I tried to use the '**NOT IN**' statement but it takes too much time. Like several minutes.

For example, the output should be :

> COUNT(*) = 20

It means that 20 tests are missing ( or not done yet ) in **table2**.

I'm using MySQL, so I can't use **EXCEPT** or **MINUS** statement.

Thank you by advance.

Nordine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can check my ans, i hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query:

```
select count(case when bname is null then 1 end)
from
(
select a.name as aname, b.name as bname from 
table1 a left join table2 b
on a.name=b.name)x
```

Comment: I'm trying but its not working. What should I write instead of a and b ?
I remplaced table1 and table2 with my table names.
name is already my column names. But what about a and b please ?

Comment: modified the query, a and b are just table name alias

Comment: Thank you. Here is my full query :
select count(case when b.test_name is null then 1 end)
from
(
select a.test_name, b.test_name from 
list_52 a left join motorcontroltests b
on a.test_name=b.test_name)x

I have an error. Telling my that the field "test_name" is already used.

Comment: select count(case when test_nameb is null then 1 end) from ( select a.test_name as test_namea, b.test_name as test_nameb from list_52 a left join motorcontroltests b on a.test_name=b.test_name)x

I've modified the query, can u please check. And this error occur as you can't select same name 2 columns

Comment: Thank you. I already left office. I will get you in touch tomorrow!

Comment: Hello. I just tried your query but it seems like i have a problem. I have no error but the output is : 'Count = 0.' And it cant be possible because there are several differences between test_name from list_52 and test_name from motorcontroltests.

Comment: can u give me your fiddle llink

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8977ba/1/0
It's working on sql fiddle but no in my DB its so weird. Thank you for your answer ! Do you know where i can add a WHERE clause for motorcontroltests. Like " WHERE LibVersion = 1.2" and only on motorcontroltests. Thanks again

Comment: Ok it's now working perfectly. The output takes like 2s but it's far better than the few minutes with the 'NOT IN' clause. Thanks a lot @fa60. Now I'm just looking to add a where clause in this query!

Comment: if it helps, please accept my answer for appreciation, thank u

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select count(*)
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.name = t1.name);
```

If you have a duplicate `name` in `table1` then you need `count(distinct t1.name)` instead.

Comment: I tried but like the 'NOT IN' statement, when I use it, the DB freezes and takes a lot of minutes to do the request.

Answer (score 0):

`MINUS` can be used in MySQL.
Ref:http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus/

Try this:

```
SELECT name
FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT name
FROM table2
```

Comment: I tried but its not working. Have a problem with MINUS statement. I'm using MySQL with WAMP and phpMyAdmin.